# Get dynamic class of element in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a table with a bunch of tr elements with random, dynamically created ids, and corresponding divs with matching ids. I want to use the on('click') function so that when one tr element with a given id is clicked, the corresponding div id is also clicked via javascript.

The table:

```
<tbody>
    <tr id="a94k5h3"></tr>
    <tr id="0f3l6k2"></tr>
    <tr id="44jg96a"></tr>
</tbody>
```

The divs:

```
<div id="a94k5h3"></div>
<div id="0f3l6k2"></div>
<div id="44jg96a"></div>
```

The code I have so far:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#view_347 #a94k5h3', function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $("#view_349 .kn-view.kn-map-results.view_349 #a94k5h3").click(); 
});
```

The above code works for the first one, but in practice I won't know what the id #a94k5h3 is, or how many tr/divs there will be. Any help would be much appreciated!

-Edit

I am using knack, which creates all of the html elements dynamically, it is not my code. I have attached an image of the output for possible clarification.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Essentially I have the same html element on a page twice. When one is clicked, I want the other one to be clicked too.

Comment: The `id` attribute is supposed to be unique. What you have there in your markup is a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: I've simplified my example quite a bit. There are multiple classes associated with both the tr elements and the div elements. The reason the ids are the same is because they both house the same information, just one is in a table and one is in a map.

Comment: Element ids should never be the same, no matter what the reasoning.

Answer (score 6):

Since you cannot have duplicate ID on a single page what I suggest you is to use the `data-*` attribute like this:

```
<tr data-id="#a94k5h3">
```

and use `.trigger("click")` to trigger the designated `click` event on the `DIV`
 Elements

#### Example:

```js
$(document).on('click', '[data-id]', function(event) {

  event.preventDefault(); // not sure you need this...

  // ID is unique! remember? you don't need the classes extra selectors
  // Use trigger "click"
  $($(this).data("id")).trigger("click");
});


// Just to test!:
$("#view_349").find("div").on("click", function() {
   console.log( this.id );
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-id="#a94k5h3"><td>a94k5h3 CLICK ME</td></tr>
    <tr data-id="#0f3l6k2"><td>0f3l6k2 CLICK ME</td></tr>
    <tr data-id="#44jg96a"><td>44jg96a CLICK ME</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<div id="view_349">
  <div id="a94k5h3">DIV a94k5h3</div>
  <div id="0f3l6k2">DIV 0f3l6k2</div>
  <div id="44jg96a">DIV 44jg96a</div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah I see the confusion. They aren't duplicate ID's they are the same element.

Comment: @DrewSchlichtmann but in your question you stated and showed in HTML that you explicitly have `<tr>` elements and `<div>` elements with the exact same ID - and asking how to trigger a click on the DIVs that share the same ID as the clicked TR... *`...so that when one tr element with a given id is clicked, the corresponding div id is also clicked via javascript...`* Can you explain more?

Comment: Both the tr and the div essentially house the same record from a database. One is displaying it in a table, and one is displaying it in a map. when the table is clicked, I want the map one to be clicked. Basically just assume that I've listed the same id twice on a page, because I want to display it twice. I apologize for not being clear.

Comment: @Drew I think you have difficulties understanding what **duplicate IDs** means. It means that in a single page you use `id="blabla"` on **two or more places**. Do like the answer suggests. Use the ID in one place - and reference it using data attribute and JS. **Or don't use IDs at all.**

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have duplicate id's in your dom, instead you should have `data-*` attributes. I chose `data-id`, but what you can do is grab the id of the clicked row, then do a selection based on that, it would look something like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'tr', (event) => { 
    event.preventDefault()
    let id = $(event.currentTarget).attr('id')
    $(`[data-id=${id}]`).addClass('selected').click()
})
```

```css
tr {background-color: red}
div.selected {background-color: yellow}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr id="a94k5h3"><td>Click Me</td></tr>
    <tr id="0f3l6k2"><td>Click Me</td></tr>
    <tr id="44jg96a"><td>Click Me</td></tr>
</table>

<div data-id="a94k5h3">1</div>
<div data-id="0f3l6k2">2</div>
<div data-id="44jg96a">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding TR element click handlers, to click a corresponding DIV element, needs a query selector that does not involve unknown random `id` values. E.G.based on the console log image:

```
"#view_349 table.kn-table TBODY TR"
```

I assume the selector for the DIV element works as provided

```
"#view_349 .kn-view.kn-map-results.view_349 #" + divId
```

Then the TR element click listener function can use the id of the TR element clicked,

```
 event.target.id
```

to find the corresponding DIV element using JQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', "#view_347 TR" function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    var targetId = event.target.id;
    $("#view_349 .kn-view.kn-map-results.view_349 #" + targetId).click(); 
});
```

This will probably work in JQuery but ignores the fact that having two elements with the same id is not valid HTML, as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5611963/5217142) and previously mentioned in comments and other answers. I recommend looking into the possibility of generating the HTML without repeating exactly the same element  id value.

Comment: They aren't duplicate Ids, they are the same Id, essentially put on the page twice. Basically all I need is when an element is clicked with x id, any other element with that id should be clicked too.

Comment: I've rewritten the answer based on the image update to the post, hope it helps. Technically "duplicate ids" means having more than one element in the document tree with the same id value.